# Iterate a map in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I have some data as seen bellow.

```
(def my-data
  {1 {:x 63 :y 14 :z [30 26]}
   2 {:x 22 :y 15 :z [32 66]}
   3 {:x 24 :y 16 :z [38 40]}})
```

I want to iterate through ***my-data*** to get the result bellow:

> 1 
>  2
>  3

This is what I have done so far

```
(println (-> (seq my-data)(ffirst ,,,)
```

and my result

> 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print each key in a different line, you can use either of these:

```
(doseq [item (keys my-data)]
   (println item))

(run! println (keys my-data))
```

Comment: So now I also want to get `x` from `my-data` collection. The thing that really confuses me is that `1,2 and 3` are not keys. I would usually use (get-in my-data [:key :x) but it is not working out for me. So basically I want  `1 [30 26] \n
2 [36 66]  \n
3 [38 40]  \n`

Comment: @magerine this worked for me: `(doseq [key (keys my-data)] (printf "%s %s%n" key (get-in my-data [key :z])))`

Answer (score 0):

You just go:

```
(println (keys my-data))
```

Comment: This is interesting. But I do not want a list as a return value.

Answer (score 0):

The non-popular answer: this will not work for bigger maps.  Small maps are ordered (insert order), but larger maps switch types and are no longer ordered/sorted.  So "first" no longer makes sense.

```clj
user=> (type (zipmap (range 8) (range 8)))
; => #<Class@34f7234e clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap>
user=> (take 8 (keys (zipmap (range 8) (range 8))))
; => (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7)
user=> (type (zipmap (range 9) (range 9)))
; => #<Class@45dd4eda clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap>
user=> (take 8 (keys (zipmap (range 9) (range 9))))
; => (0 7 1 4 6 3 2 5)
```

The other answers are correct for larger maps, if you you it via `sorted-map` or `sorted-map-by`, if sorting your keys solves the problem.  If you need the order you might be better off using vectors of vectors.